# Where does all of this javascript go anyway?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```
<div id="title">
  <h1>Explore Your Lending Options</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="filter_projects">Filter Projects</button> </br>
    <%= render partial: "shared/project_filters" %>
    <div id="projects"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script charset="utf-8">
  $("#filter_projects").on("click", function() {
        $("#filters").animate({width: "toggle"}, 1000);
      });
</script>

<script charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var auth_token = " <%= form_authenticity_token %>"

    var cleanFilters = function(filters) {
      var cleanedFilters = [];
      filters.forEach(function(element) {
        cleanedFilters.push(element.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]);
      });
      return cleanedFilters;
    }

    var appendProject = function(project) {
      $("#projects").append(
        "<div><a href='/" + project.organization + "/projects/" + project.id + "'>" + project.title + "</a></div>" +
        "<a href='/" + project.organization + "/projects/" + project.id + "'><img src='" + project.image_url +
        "' width='250px' height='auto'></a>" + "<div class='project-desc'>" + project.description + "</div>" +
        '<form action="/pending_loan" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden"' +
        'value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="' + auth_token + '" />' +
        '<input value="1" type="hidden" name="pending_loan[project_id]" id="pending_loan_' + project.id + '" />' +
        '<input value="2500" type="hidden" name="pending_loan[loan_amount]" id="pending_loan_loan_amount" />' +
        '<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Lend $25" class="btn btn-default" /></form>'
      )
    }

    var appendProjects = function(projects) {
      projects.forEach(function(project) {
        appendProject(project);
      });
    };

    var renderProjects = function(filteredProjects) {
      $("#projects").empty();
      console.log(filteredProjects);
      appendProjects(filteredProjects);
    };

    var filterProjectsByCategory = function(projects, checkedFilters) {
      return projects.filter(function(project) {
        return project.categories.some(function(category) {
          return checkedFilters.indexOf(category) > -1;
        });
      });
    };

    var filterProjects = function(projects, checkedFilters) {
      projectsFilteredByCategory = filterProjectsByCategory(projects, checkedFilters);
      //return filterProjectsByPrice(projectsFilteredByCategory, checkedFilters);
      return projectsFilteredByCategory;
    };

    var all_projects;
    $.getJSON("/projects.json", function(data) {
      all_projects= data;
      console.log(all_projects);
      var initial_category_selected = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('=') + 1);
      //window.location.search gives us query parameters. so that's sick
      var initial_categories = [];
      initial_categories.push(initial_category_selected);
      var filteredProjects = filterProjects(all_projects, initial_categories);
      renderProjects(filteredProjects);
    });

    $(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
      var filters = [];
      $("input:checked").each(function(index) {
        filters.push(this.name);
      });
      var cleanedFilters = cleanFilters(filters);
      var filteredProjects = filterProjects(all_projects, cleanedFilters)
      renderProjects(filteredProjects);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The above is my index.html.erb file which has a bunch of erb, html, and javascript functions. Where should I put all of my javascript functions? Where do they all go? Where does all of my jquery go? Is there a a way that  I can do without all of the  tags?

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to put your javascript file to app/assets/javascripts folder.

You can choose one approach based on your needs.
There are two ways to include javascript files:

1) if you want that javascript file to be included only in one page you can write the following code in your view:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'file.js'
```

and add the following line to config/environment/production.rb (it's needed to make rails precompile file in production mode):

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(file.js)
```

After that you can use this file only in page where you connected it.

2) you can add this line to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require file
```

after that you can use your javascript code in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can keep all your jquery,javascript functions in the

```
  app/assets/javascripts folder
```

the application.js will automatically call all the javascripts which are required.

Answer (score -1):

The ideal way in rails is to put your javascript in folder `app/assets/javascripts` corresponding to your controller's name,

e.g. if you have a `projects_controller` then you can put your corresponding javascript code in `app/assets/javascripts/projects.js`

This will be automatically loaded on your `index` page, because of this line in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file 
`//= require .`
This loads all available js files in that folder.

But this approach unnecessarily loads other js files as well which might not be required for that view, To get rid of it
remove `//= require .` from application.js
and add `javascript_include_tag 'projects.js'` to your index.html.erb file e.g.

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "projects.js" %>
<% end %>
```

This way this javascript is loaded only on views in which you have used it. 

For jquery i am assuming you are already using gem (as you have not loaded it by any script tag on index.html.erb), you need to just require it in your application.js file like this: 
`//= require jquery`

For more digging you can try [Layout and rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)